# swiftui delete row in Table

Tags: swiftui

I need some help with a strange behavior in Apple's new Table view (since macOS 12).

```
Table(diagnoses, sortOrder: $diagnoses.sortDescriptors) {
    TableColumn("ICD10", value: \.icd!) { dia in
        Text(dia.icd ?? "XXX.X")
    }
    .width(min: 30, ideal: 40, max: 50)
    TableColumn("diagnosis", value: \.diagnosis!) { dia in
        Text(dia.diagnosis ?? "notSpec")
    }
    TableColumn("gestellt", value: \.madeOn!) { dia in
        if dia.madeOn != nil {
            Text(Formatters.dateFormatter.string(from: dia.madeOn!))
        }
    }
    .width(min: 60, ideal: 70, max: 80)
    TableColumn("") { dia in
        HStack {
            Button(
                action: {
print(dia) // <<-- here correct "dia"
                    showDiaDelAlert.toggle()
                },
                label: {
                    Image(systemName: "trash")
                }
            )
            .buttonStyle(.borderless).foregroundColor(Color.accentColor)
            Button(
                action: {
                    showingDiaEditScreen.toggle()
                },
                label: {
                    Image(systemName: "pencil")
                }
            )
            .buttonStyle(.borderless).foregroundColor(Color.accentColor)
        }
        .confirmationDialog("alertDelete", isPresented: $showDiaDelAlert) {
            Button("ok", role: .destructive){
print(dia) // <<-- here other "dia". Mainly the first item in Table
                deleteItem(item: dia, moc: moc)
            }
            Button("cancel", role: .cancel) {
                showDiaDelAlert.toggle()
            }.keyboardShortcut(.defaultAction)
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingDiaEditScreen) {
            EditDiagnosisView(diagno: dia)
        }
    }
    .width(min: 30, ideal: 40, max: 50)
}
.tableStyle(.bordered(alternatesRowBackgrounds: true))
```

Everything works fine so far. But with editing (showing sheet), and deleting there are some problems.

- Editing: the form in the sheet doesn't display the right row and when closing the sheet, for every other row die sheet is displayed again.
- Deleting: the wrong row is deleted, and the alert appears once again. Confirmation will delete the next / previous row, too.

I need to place buttons, because Table doesn't offer swipe actions (or?). And I need to place the `.confirmationDialog` and the `.sheet` somewhere within the `TableColumn` to get the `dia`.

Any ideas, what's wrong and how to solve this?

Comment: For 'Editing", you could try using `.sheet(item: ...)` and putting it outside the `Table{...}` . For  "Deleting" it is best if you could show the code for it.

Comment: OmG, the problem was sitting in front of the computer. :-) I forgot to save the UUID for the entity. @workingdogsupportUkraine: Thanks for your quick response. You're great!

Comment: Ok, sorry again. Problem still not solved. Suddenly the same strange behavior. Clicking on delete button, will delete wrong (first) row. (see added comment do code above).

Comment: My findings so far: the problem seems to be somewhere in the `.confirmationDialog`. Testing without the dialog everything works fine.

Comment: Not nice but working: store my `dia` to a variable and place the `.confirmationDialog` outside the `Table`